# Why I can't retrieve data from session and rows of session table auto increase in CodeIgniter3?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I've create new web app using **Codeigniter3** and I have a problem on session data.

**Issue 1**: I can't retrieve any data from my session data although it existing in database.

**Issue 2:**  Rows of session table automatically increase and never deleted although I enable sess_expire_on_close to True. And When I refresh pages in Firefox 4 rows of table session will increase the same time. so it will increase to more and more rows if my web pages refresh more and it will increase one by one if I refresh in Chrome browser.

**Notes:** I've already clean my browser data or session and reinstall new.

Please check on my configure.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'tb_session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Please check on my attachment to see the increasing of rows when chrome and firefox refresh pages.

And I've also can retrieve any data from table session when I used this method

```
$this->data['f'] = $this->session->userdata('email');
```

And this is images of increasing rows when refresh pages

[image]

And this is in Firefox 4rows per refresh

[image]

Comment: It is not valid CI3 configuration. It is CI2 configuration properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confused between CI2 and CI3
Here is CI3 configure

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'com';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400*365;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

And I've confused on Session table ID Please check below

```
CREATE TABLE "ci_sessions" (
        "id" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        "ip_address" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        "timestamp" bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        "data" text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

After that CI3 Session is helpfully